# Using Nokia Maps in a Java desktop application

Tags: here-api

Some years ago, my company developed a desktop application in Java using map24 api (by Mapsolute, bought by Navteq which was recently adquired by Nokia). Now we are facing problems with it due to recent changes in ways to access the maps. I checked the site developer.here.com and couldn't find an API for Java SE (just ME).

The question is: what must we do in order to use here.com maps in our Java application with all the features like polygons, markers and so forth?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that API is no more.
What I know you can do is use the [JavaScript API](http://developer.here.com/javascript_api) from your desktop application. As far as I can tell, the JavaScript API is the most complete one in HERE.

For information on using JavaScript from Java apps, I found this [article](https://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/) (but not really tested it)

You can also access most of the functionality through the [REST API](http://developer.here.com/rest_api), which is even better, if it provides what your application need.

Comment: Thanks molusco. I'm going to use JavaScript API and JavaFX (WebView).